# How to obtain text stored in Mysql Mediumblob through Java?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in Java and am not understanding how to obtain a paragraph of text that I have stored in Mysql database as a Mediumblob through Java.  Below is the section of my code that I'm having problems with.  I've successfully obtained other stored data in the form of VARCHAR and INT through .getString() and .getInt().  I did try .getObject() below but that didn't seem to work.  Any insight would be appreciated ~ thank you.

```
    try{
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);  
        pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM exercise WHERE exercise_name = Clams;");
        rs = pst.executeQuery();  

        while (rs.next()){

            java.sql.Blob id = rs.getBlob("description");
            System.out.print(id);
        }

    }catch(SQLException ex){

    }finally {
        try {
            if (rs != null){
                rs.close();
            }
            if (pst != null){
                pst.close();
            }
            if (con != null){
                con.close();
            }
        }catch(SQLException ex){
        }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
java.sql.Blob id = rs.getBlob("description");
String s = new String(id.getBytes(0,id.length()));
```

Comment: Thanks, I gave it a try and it compiles but nothing comes up on the console BUT, I just realized something...in the database I have this text saved and imported as a .txt file so I'm assuming that I need to use fileReader to read this .txt file that I'm trying to obtain from the database?